# What is the fastest way to create a function if its creation depends upon some other input parameters?

Tags: python, function

I have an API that supports (unfortunately) too many ways for a user to give inputs. I have to create a function depending upon the type of inputs. Once the function has been created (lets call it foo), it is run many times (around 10^7 times).

The user first gives 3 inputs - A, B and C that tell us about the types of input given to our foo function. A can have three possible values, B can have four and C can have 5. Thus giving me 60 possible permutations. 
Example - if A is a list then the first parameter for foo will be a type list and similarly for B and C.

Now I cannot make these checks inside the function `foo` for obvious reasons. Hence, I create a function create_foo that checks for all the possible combinations and returns a unique function foo. But the drawback with this approach is that I have to write the foo function 60 times for all the permutations.
An example of this approach -

```
def create_foo(A,B,C):
    if A=='a1' and B=='b1' and C=='c1':
        def foo(*args):
            /*calls some functions that parse the given parameters*/
            /*does something*/
        return foo

    if A=='a2' and B=='b1' and C=='c1':
        def foo(*args):
            /*calls some functions that parse the given parameters*/
            /*does something*/
        return foo

    if A=='a3' and B=='b1' and C=='c1':
        def foo(*args):
            /*calls some functions that parse the given parameters*/
            /*does something*/
        return foo

          .
          .
          .
          .(60 times)

          .
          .
          .
    if A=='a3' and B=='b4' and C=='c5':
        def foo(*args):
            /*calls some functions that parse the given parameters*/
            /*does something*/
        return foo
```

The foo function parses the parameters differently every time, but then it performs the same task after parsing.

Now I call the function

```
f = create_foo(A='a2',B='b3',C='c4')
```

Now foo is stored in `f` and `f` is called many times. Now `f` is very time efficient but the problem with this approach is the messy code which involves writing the foo function 60 times.

Is there a cleaner way to do this? I cannot compromise on performance hence, the new method must not take more time for evaluation that this method.

Currying lamda functions to handle all this takes more time than the above method because of the extra function calls. I cannot afford it.

**A,B and C are not used by the function they are only used for parsing values and they would not change after the creation of `foo`.
For example - if A is a type list no change is required but if its a dict it needs to call a function that parses dict to list. A,B and C only tell us about the type of parameters in `*args`**

Comment: I can't put together an answer based on this, especially because I'm not much of a pythonist, but it seems to me that currying a lambda that handled all these situations might help, though it's just a hunch that I thought might give somebody more knowledgable an idea  https://mtomassoli.wordpress.com/2012/03/18/currying-in-python/

Comment: Yes it will allow writing the foo function only once but it is slower than the former method which i cannot afford

Comment: We'd have to know how `foo` depends on `A`, `B`, and `C`. I would guess that this `create_foo` function is a misguided optimization, though. If checking `A`, `B`, and `C` inside the call is really a performance killer relative to whatever else goes on inside `foo`, you may want to consider using something like Cython, which will provide a much better speedup than what you're doing here.

Comment: @user2357112 Lets say that if type (A) is a list then it takes it directly but if a dict it parses it to a list. Similarly for B and C as well.

Comment: @YashuSeth: I'd say to just provide the input-processing functions to `foo` through default argument values or closure variables or `functools.partial` or something. (I'm surprised you're not inlining the input-processing functions, though, if you consider the `A`, `B`, and `C` checks too much work to put into `foo`.)

Comment: There simply isn't enough information given in the question for a sensible answer here. Probably the answer is to just write the code in the obvious way with one 'foo' function and forget about performance until it works, then *if you have to* optimise the slow parts by rewriting them in something like Cython.

Comment: Are A,B,C used to demarshal or are their values actually used in the bodies of `foo` functions?

Comment: @DmitryRubanovich No the values are not used in the foo function.

Comment: are A,B and C mutually dependent?? if not you don't have to make all combinations, only one for each case of each variable, so only 12

Answer (score 1):

It's not 100% clear what you want, but I'll assume `A`, `B`, and `C` are the same as the `*args` to `foo`.

Here are some thoughts toward possible solutions:

(1) I wouldn't take it for granted that your 60 `if` statements necessarily make an impact. If the rest of your function is at all computationally demanding, you might not even notice the proportional increase in running time from 60 `if` statements.

(2) You could parse/sanity-check the arguments *once* (slowly/inefficiently) and then pass the sanity-checked versions to a single function `foo` that runs 10^7 times.

(3) You could write a single function `foo` that handles every case, but only let it parse/sanity check arguments if a certain optional keyword is provided:

```
def foo( A, B, C, check=False ):

    if check:
        pass # TODO: implement sanity-checking on A, B and C here

    pass   # TODO: perform computationally-intensive stuff here
```

Call `foo(..., check=True )` once.  Then call it without `check=True` 10^7 times.

(4) If you want to pass around multiple versions of the same callable function, each version configured with different argument values pre-filled, that's what `functools.partial` is for.  This may be what you want, rather than duplicating the same code 60 times.

Answer (score 0):

Whoa whoa whoa. You're saying you're duplicating code ***SIXTY TIMES*** in your function? No, that will not do. Here's what you do instead.

```
def coerce_args(f):
    def wrapped(a, b, c):
        if isinstance(a, list):
            pass
        elif isinstance(a, dict):
            a = list(a.items())  # turn it into a list
        # etc for each argument
        return f(a, b, c)
    return wrapped

@coerce_args
def foo(a, b, c): 
    """foo will handle a, b, c in a CONCRETE form"""
    # do stuff
```

Essentially you're building one decorator that's going to change `a`, `b`, and `c` into a known format for `foo` to handle the business logic on. You've already built an API where it's acceptable to call this in a number of different ways (which is bad to begin with), so you need to support it. Doing so means *internally* treating it as the same way every time, and providing a helper to coerce that.

Comment: I asked and he seems to indicate that the code will not be replicated.  The values of A,B,C will only be used to demarshal which function gets returned.  Seems like he is trying to get around not having a switch statement.

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't specify what actually happens in each individual foo, there is not way to generalize how foo's are created.  But there is a way to speed up demarshaling.

```
def create_foo(A,B,C, d={}):
    if len(d) == 0:
        def _111():
            def foo(*args):
            /*calls some functions that parse the given parameters*/
            /*does something*/
            return foo
        d[('a1','b1','c1')] = _111
        def _211():
            def foo(*args):
            /*calls some functions that parse the given parameters*/
            /*does something*/
            return foo
        d[('a2','b1','c1')] = _211
        ....
        def _345():
            def foo(*args):
            /*calls some functions that parse the given parameters*/
            /*does something*/
            return foo
        d[('a3','b4','c5')] = _345
    return d[(A,B,C)]()
```

The _XXX functions will not be evaluated each time you call create_foo.  So the functions will only be created at run-time.  Also the **default** value of `d` will be set when the `create_foo` function is defined (only once).  So after the first run, the code inside the if statement will not be entered anymore and the dictionary will have all the functions ready to start initializing and returning your foo's.

Edit: if the behavior in each `foo` is the same (as the edit of the question seems to suggest), then rather than passing types of `foo`'s parameters in A,B and C, maybe its better to pass in conversion functions?  Then the whole thing becomes:

```
def create_foo(L1, L2, L3):
    def foo(a,b,c):
        a=L1(a)
        b=L2(b)
        c=L3(c)
        /*does something*/
    return foo
```

If you want to (for example) convert all 3 parameters to sets from lists, then you can call it as:

```
f = create_foo(set,set,set)
```

If you want foo to add 1 to 1st parameter, subtract 5 from second and multiply 3rd by 4, you'd say

```
f = create_foo(lambda x:x+1, lambda x:x-5, lambda x:x*4)
```

Comment: This seems perfect to me. Maybe even avoid the performance hit of currying during runtime by rolling this into your server init, keep a copy of the whole table in memory, and have `foo(a, b, c)` just passthrough to the table (`def foo(a, b, c): return server.footable[(a,b,c,)]()`)

Comment: @Adam Smith, I tried to stick to the original implementation of not compiling all the foo's at startup.  It does mean that the returned functions will be recompiled before create_foo returns them, but the question seemed to have that intention in mind.

Answer (score 0):

given your vague explanation I will make some assumptions and work with that.
I will assume that `A`, `B` and `C` are mutually independent, and that they are parsed to the same type, then I give you this

```
def _foo(*argv,parser_A=None,parser_B=None,parser_C=None):
    if parser_A is not None:
        #parse your A arguments here
    if parser_B is not None:
        #parse your B arguments here
    if parser_C is not None:
        #parse your C arguments here
   # do something

def foo_maker(A,B,C):
    parser_A = None
    parser_B = None
    parser_C = None
    if A == "list": #or isinstance(A,list)
        pass
    elif A == "dict": #or isinstance(A,dict)
        #put your parse here, for example:
        parser_A = lambda x: x.items() 

    ...

    #the same with B and C
    return lambda *argv: _foo(*argv, parser_A=parser_A, parser_B=parser_B, parser_C=parser_C )
```

simple working example

```
def _foo(*argv,parser_A=None,parser_B=None,parser_C=None):
    if parser_A is not None:
        argv = parser_A(argv)
    if parser_B is not None:
        argv = parser_B(argv)
    if parser_C is not None:
        argv = parser_C(argv)
    print(argv)

def foo_maker(A,B,C):
    pa = None
    pb = None
    pc = None
    if A==1:
        pa = lambda x: (23,32)+x
    if B==2:
        pb = lambda x: list(map(str,x))
    if C==3:
        pc = lambda x: set(x)
    return lambda *x:_foo(*x,parser_A=pa,parser_B=pb,parser_C=pc)
```

test

```
>>> f1=foo_maker(1,4,3)
>>> f2=foo_maker(1,2,3)
>>> f1(1,2,3,5,8)
{32, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 23}
>>> f2(1,2,3,5,8)
{'8', '23', '2', '3', '5', '1', '32'}
>>> f3=foo_maker(0,0,3)
>>> f3(1,2,3,5,8)
{8, 1, 2, 3, 5}
>>> f4=foo_maker(0,0,0)
>>> f4(1,2,3,5,8)
(1, 2, 3, 5, 8)
>>> f5=foo_maker(1,0,0)
>>> f5(1,2,3,5,8)
(23, 32, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8)
>>>
```